# Installing h3 on Windows correctly

Tags: python-3.x, h3

I'm getting an error when I try to installed the *h3* package via pip. I running  Python 3.6.

Here's the error:

> Command "d:\pyth2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='c:\users\8523~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0frm_v\h3\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record c:\users\8523~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-gizroq\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\8523~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0frm_v\h3\

How do I bypass this error?

I've installed all pre-required packages, except "make" which is unavailable on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Use Conda forge. 
There is a h3-py package

Answer (score 0):

While you can install `make` through conda, but it will not solve this problem. On h3-py page they said it's better not to use pip on windows and use cmake to install it instead.

See this reply:
https://github.com/uber/h3-py/issues/18#issuecomment-441454667

Or you can use the linux subsystem in windows to avoid any programming hassles.

Answer (score 0):

The most useful advice is https://github.com/uber/h3-py/issues/32

For install H3-py on Windows 10 you need to have:

1. Any C++ compiler, for example - Visual Studio 2017
2. Cmake
3. Git for Windows
4. Windows subsystem for Linux (https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/install-win10). I'd recommend Kali. On linux you need to install packages - git, cmake and something else - follow the requirements of system.
5. Python 2.6 (in my case)

Then download h3-py - https://github.com/uber/h3-py

In folder h3-py-master there is a file "requirements-dev.txt". You need to install packages with Powershell (pip install -r "requirements-dev.txt"). Then you need to add some lines in script .install.sh:

...

```
VERSION=$1
IS_64BITS=$2
OS=Windows_NT
```

...

```
if [[ "True" == "$IS_64BITS" ]]; then
    cmake . -DENABLE_FORMAT=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
```

And after all type in Powershell :

```
.install.sh v3.4.2 True
```

In subfolder "out" you will find "h3.dll". Copy to ".../python/DLLs"